# Querying JSONB in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, json, cast, postgresql-9.5, operator

I have a table, `persons`, which contains two columns, an `id` and a JSONB-based `data` column (this table has just been made for demonstrational purposes to play around with PostgreSQL's JSON support).

Now, supposed it contains two records:

```
1, { name: 'John', age: 30 }
2, { name: 'Jane', age: 20 }
```

Now, supposed I want to get the name of every person older than 25. What I have tried is:

```
select data->'name' as name from persons where data->'age' > 25
```

Unfortunately, this results in an error. I can solve it by using `->>` instead of `->`, but then comparisons don't work as expected any more, since not the numbers are compared, but their representations as strings:

```
select data->'name' as name from persons where data->>'age' > '25'
```

I then figured out that I can actually solve the issue by using `->` and a cast to `int`:

```
select data->'name' as name from persons where cast(data->'age' as int) > 25
```

This works, but it's not that nice that I have to know the actual type (the type of `age` in the JSON document is `number` anyway, so why can't PostgreSQL figure out that by itself?).

I then figured out that if I manually convert to `text` using the `::` syntax, everything works as expected, too - although we are now comparing strings again.

```
select data->'name' as name from persons where data->'age'::text > '25'
```

If I then try this with the name instead of the age, it doesn't work:

```
select data->'name' as name from persons where data->'name'::text > 'Jenny'
```

This results in an error:

> invalid input syntax for type json

Pretty obviously, I don't get something here. Unfortunately, it's quite hard to find any real-world examples of using JSON with PostgreSQL.

Any hints?

Comment: In `data->'name'::text`, you are casting the `'name'` string to text, not the result. You don’t get an error when comparing to `'25'` because `25` is a valid JSON literal; but `Jenny` is not (although `"Jenny"` would be).

Comment: Thanks, that's the solution :-). I confused `'Jenny'` with `'"Jenny"'`.

Answer (score 26):

This does not work because it's trying to cast a `jsonb` value to `integer`.

```
select data->'name' as name from persons where cast(data->'age' as int) > 25
```

*This* would actually work:

```
SELECT data->'name' AS name FROM persons WHERE cast(data->>'age' AS int) > 25;
```

Or shorter:

```
SELECT data->'name' AS name FROM persons WHERE (data->>'age')::int > 25;
```

And this:

```
SELECT data->'name' AS name FROM persons WHERE data->>'name' > 'Jenny';
```

Seems like confusion with the two [operators `->` and `->>`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-OP-TABLE) and [operator precedence](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-PRECEDENCE). The cast `::` binds stronger than the json(b) operators.

#### Figure out type dynamically

This is the more interesting part of your question:

> the type of age in the JSON document is number anyway, so why can't PostgreSQL figure out that by itself?

SQL is a strictly typed language, it does not allow the same expression to evaluate to `integer` in one row and to `text` in the next. But since you are only interested in the `boolean` result of the test, you can get around this restriction with a `CASE` expression that forks depending on the result of [**`jsonb_typeof()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE):

```
SELECT data->'name'
FROM   persons
WHERE  CASE jsonb_typeof(data->'age')
        WHEN 'number'  THEN (data->>'age')::numeric > '25' -- treated as numeric
        WHEN 'string'  THEN data->>'age' > 'age_level_3'   -- treated as text
        WHEN 'boolean' THEN (data->>'age')::bool           -- use boolean directly (example)
        ELSE FALSE                                         -- remaining: array, object, null
       END;
```

An untyped string literal to the right of the `>` operator is coerced to the respective type of the value to the left automatically. If you put a typed value there, the type has to match or you have to cast it explicitly - unless there is adequate implicit cast registered in the system.

If you *know* that all *numeric* values are actually `integer`, you can also:

```
... (data->>'age')::int > 25 ...
```

Comment: what is the sqlalchemy core expression for the above comparison of select statement eg. s=select([issues]).where(issues.c.id == mid).select_from(issues,..... outerjoin(issues.c.data['type_id'] == mtypes.c.id))   ...Here issues.c.data jsonb data type and  is being compared with mtypes.c.id  of integer type

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this:

```
select jb.id, t.*
from (select '{"id": 1, "value": "test"}'::jsonb as json
      union select '{"id": 2, "value": "test2"}'::jsonb
      ) as t
     left join lateral (
          select *
          from jsonb_to_record(t.json) as (id int, nonexistent_col text)
      ) jb on true
 where jb.id = 1;
```

returns:

```
 id| json
 --|--------------------------
  1| {"id": 1, "value": "test"}
```

I included nonexistent_col to make sure that if i have one record with one json key and another without it, i can still query it without error. Just make sure that an "int" will suffice for all the data for the "id" field. It WILL error if you try to supply a column definition and the field does not fit in it.

UPDATE: after posting, realized that the following is much better, as it allows the use of indexes, such as:

```
--create index ix_table_column_element on table((json_col->'element'));

select t.*
from (select '{"id": 1, "value": "test"}'::jsonb as json
      union select '{"id": 2, "value": "test2"}'::jsonb
      ) as t
where json->'id' = to_jsonb(1);
```